# Free Trial IAP + Non-Renewing Subscription IAP

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm confused about the the following statement in the apple's review guidelines 3.1.1

"**Non-subscription apps** may offer a free time-based trial period before presenting a full unlock option by setting up a Non-Consumable IAP item at Price Tier 0 that follows the naming convention: “XX-day Trial.” ..."

Current situation: 
This is my first app and not published yet. It's planned to be offered at no cost. I've already implemented a non-renewing subscription IAP item to unlock all features for a period of time. The app keeps still useful without buying the IAP item.

Questions:
What's the meaning of "non-subscription apps"?

Does it mean that I am not eligible to offer a free trial period IAP item (Non-Consumable item at price 0)?

Comment: Subscriptions can already include a free trial period; you can set that up on the subscription IAP. The process you describe is for non-subscription apps that want to offer a free trial

Comment: I can setup a free trial period for auto-renewable subscription IAPs but not for a non-renewing subscription. Therefore I would like to add this functionality with an additional non-consumable IAP item. The core question is actually whether my app is considered as a „subscription app“ because it provides a non-renewing subscription IAP?

Comment: I can't see why you couldn't use the same mechanism with a non-renewing subscription. All you can do is submit your app and see what Apple says.

Comment: Because you can configure it on the appstoreconnect only for the auto-renewable type. When I configure a non-consumable item for the free trial, I have to implement some stuff on my app's backend to check the state of the item. I don't want to do it just with the hope that apple will approve.

Comment: Unfortunately only Apple can give you an answer and the only way you can get a answer is to submit your app for review. The only IAP type that directly supports free trial is auto renewing. If you don't want to use that then you need to roll your own using a free non-consumable and, most likely, using device check.  You could also just use device check to unlock full app functionality for the first X days and then ask for a subscription